# XAML Windows 8 app: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-8.1

This issue occurs while I clear an observable collection.
This is XAML Windows 8 app
Sample code-

```
private static MovieNewsDataSource _dataSource = new MovieNewsDataSource();
private ObservableCollection<DataGroup> _allGroups = new ObservableCollection<DataGroup>();
public ObservableCollection<DataGroup> AllGroups
{
get { return this._allGroups; }
}


public void MovieNews_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, ResponseStringArgs e)
        {
            try
            {

                var group = new DataGroup("Group-1",
                   "movie news") { GroupBg = "Green", ItemsRow = "1" };

                var newsObject = e.Result.ToSerializeObject<Data.CelebNews>();

                foreach (var item in newsObject.CelebNewsItems)
                {
                    group.Items.Add(new DataItem(item.NewsTitleInfo.Id,
                            item.NewsTitleInfo.Title,
                            item.Details,"",
                            item.Thumbnail3,
                            item.Thumbnail,
                            item.NewsTitleInfo.Date,
                            item.Writer,
                            group));
                }
                _dataSource.AllGroups.Clear(); //<-- Issue occurs here
                if (group.Items.Count > 0)
                {
                    _dataSource.AllGroups.Add(group);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //TODO: Exception handling
                _dataSource.AllGroups.Clear();
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
            }
        }
```

Exception details-
System.AccessViolationException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=System
  StackTrace:
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection`1.ClearItems()
       at System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection`1.Clear()
       at Data.TrailerDataSource.TrailerData_DownloadStringCompleted(Object sender, ResponseStringArgs e) in DataModel\TrailerDataSource.cs:line 376
       at RequestResponseManager.cs:line 32
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.InvokeMoveNext(Object stateMachine)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.MoveNextRunner.Run()
       at System.Threading.Tasks.SynchronizationContextAwaitTaskContinuation.<.cctor>b__3(Object state)
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeCore()
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.InvokeInContext(Object thisObj)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.WinRTSynchronizationContext.Invoker.Invoke()
  InnerException:

Comment: What's your question? Have you tried to figure out why it occurs? Simply the code ... change the structure, etc.?

Comment: Firstly, in your error handling, you shouldn't `throw ex` - just `throw`.  Secondly, I would remove that error handling completely while you try to find the issue (or ctrl-alt-e and turn on break on thrown CLR exceptions). 

_DownloadStringCompleted seems to be an event, but you haven't said what kind... and it does seem to be relevant to the error.